# iPhone: How to create a UIButton from a xib, or a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, uibutton, xib, nib

Is there some way to make a custom UIButton which apparence inherits from a xib file or a uiview?

In android I can inflate a layout and use it as the view of a button, is this possible in iphone?

I created a class that inherits from UIButton, and tried to create a xib file for it with a view where I could place other elements inside and link them to the class. I made this view the type of my class, but it did not seem to work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

UIButton inherits directly from UIView so yes, you can utilized a customized UIView for a UIButton.

Comment: any tip on how? I didn't find much stuff on this matter